# iMac 27-inch, Late 2014, RAM upgrade size combinations

Tags: memory, compatibility

There are 4 slots. 2 slots taken by 2x4GB that came with Mac at purchase. Max memory is specified as 32GB. Can I buy 1x8GB and 1x16GB to fill the remaining 2 slots. Or do I need to use 8GB for both remaining slots. Thank you!

Comment: Personally I would put 2 or 4 matching memory modules in the slots - just to avoid possible mis-matching.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is you can mismatch sizes **in pairs** but not in individual slots.
Computers use interleaved memory, which requires each pair of slots to be populated with the exact same RAM. Having mis-matched slots will 'break' the interleaving & slow down the RAM access. As far as I'm aware this isn't 'dangerous' at all, merely slower.

Some machines can also use triple-channel memory, where three matching memory sticks can be interleaved. I don't know whether your iMac can do that, it may only be the Mac Pros that can - though in this case would make your issue harder to solve [I'm just including it for completeness]

So, your ideal way to achieve 32GB would be 4 x 8GB, which is probably cheaper than 2 x 16 anyway. If you keep the existing 4's I would add a pair of 8's.

[Crucial's RAM configurator](https://uk.crucial.com/gbr/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Apple/imac-%28retina-5k%2C-27-inch%2C-late-2014%29-imac15%2C1), on a quick search [check for your exact model] shows no 16GB sticks at all.